# htaccess Rewrite in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I had to remove .php extension and I got success  with using

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now I had to create pretty url 
as
ssfront/category/id/MQ../t/f/name/Accounting From
ssfront/category.php?id=1&t=f&name=Accounting 
And I got success using

```
 RewriteRule category/id/(.*)/t/(.*)/name/(.*) category.php?id=$1&t=$2&name=$3 [L,B]
```

But get problem when I echo $_GET['name'] , It gives Accounting.php

ie

echo $_GET['name']

out put : Accounting.php instead of Accounting

But i actually need Accounting as output

I tried solution

```
     $name_ =  substr($_GET['name'], 0,strrpos($_GET['name'],'.'));
```

But I dont think this is solution should be apply
so Is there any  master and easy solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule category/id/(.*)/t/(.*)/name/(.*) category.php?id=$1&t=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]
```

## Update:

This .htaccess work fine in my server:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^category/id/([^/]+)/t/([^/]+)/name/(.*)(?:.php)$ category.php?id=$1&t=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]
```

In category.php (with url `test.local/category/id/1/t/2/name/3`:

```
var_dump($_GET['name']);
// Output: string(1) "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it this way:

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^category/id/([^/]+)/t/([^/]+)/name/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&t=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried this code but it didnt work , gives same result

Comment: Don't you think your accepted answer looks exactly same as my answer?

Comment: #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]  -------  (?:.php)

Comment: Any line that starts with a `#` is a commented line :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use basename function for example:

```
$name_ =  basename($_GET['name']);
```

Comment: didnt work , and actually  dont want to use php code